# R hanging when running a lmer

Tags: r, lme4

I'm trying to use `lmer` from the `lme4` package to run a linear mixed model. 
The dataframe contains `14204 obs. of 7 variables` and is `927.9 KB`.  I'm running it through R studio using `R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23) -- "Joy in Playing"` on MacOS.

When I run the following command R just hangs ...

`score.model <- lmer(Score ~ factor(Title) + (1|Judge), data = df);`

I'm wondering if anyone has any idea why this is causing R to hang and how I might be able to deal with the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by *"R just hangs"*? This is a fairly simple model, and `lmer` shouldn't take long to finish. I assume the problem is elsewhere. Try executing from a fresh terminal (don't save the previous workspace).

Comment: Tried that.  It simply doesn’t return to another prompt to run another command

Comment: What happens if you take a smaller subset of your df and run the model? Or just try to run some example data from the vignette? Do those work?

Comment: How many levels of `Title` and `Judge` are there? Also, unrelated to the issue: it's better for `Title` to be a factor in the dataset, before running the model.

Comment: `Title` =7102 `Judge`=86

Comment: @Esther runs quickly if I run just on the first 100 entries by doing `test <- head(df,100)`

Comment: I think neilfws is right, you have too many levels of `Title`, essentially you're fitting 7102 parameters. I think I saw somewhere that `lmer` can't really run over 1000.  And it doesn't really make since to model a parameter if there's only ~2 cases of it on average.

Comment: @Esther Thanks ... btw this is relatd to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347931/accounting-for-differences-between-judge-scoring/349109?noredirect=1#comment659897_349109)

Comment: Ah, I see. I think those responses were generally correct, but they didn't think about the relative number of factor levels. Presumably these scores (once standardized to Judge) will be part of another analysis? Those details might be important if you want to edit your CV question. @neilfws I think you could write an answer here if you wanted